# In solr query hyphen is replaced with question mark

Tags: solr

I have two different collections- test1 and test3 in SolrCloud. When I search for `"BUG-123"` in test1 I see following parsed query in debug section.

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "\"BUG-123\"",
    "querystring": "\"BUG-123\"",
    "parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(_text_:\"bug 123\")",
    "parsedquery_toString": "_text_:\"bug 123\"",
...}
```

Whereas When I search for `"BUG-123"` in `test3` I see following parsed query in debug section.

```
"debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "\"BUG-123\"",
    "querystring": "\"BUG-123\"",
    "parsedquery": "PhraseQuery(_text_:\"bug ? 123\")",
    "parsedquery_toString": "_text_:\"bug ? 123\"",
...}
```

Please note in case of `test3` , `"-"` character gets replaced with `"?"`. Due to this I do not get any documents in search result.

I need help to understand why `-` gets replaced with `?` and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue. In managed-schema file for test3 collection, I had included AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory in query section for text_en field type, as follows

```
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<filter class="com.lucidworks.analysis.AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory" includeTokens="true" phrases="autophrases.txt"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Removing following line  and restarting solr cloud resolved issue.

```
<filter class="com.lucidworks.analysis.AutoPhrasingTokenFilterFactory" includeTokens="true" phrases="autophrases.txt"/>
```